# Dock or Anchor properties for microsoft reporting in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting, report-viewer2010

When working with ReportViewer in Winforms and Microsoft reports is possible to have a way to dynamically resize the report in the screen like anchors and dock property in "common" controls?

I can turn on docking for ReportViewer, but the contents does not resize, only the control.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to catch the resize event and tell the report to refresh (it has a `.Refresh()`).  I'm not 100% sure on this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to resize the report to fit on the page.

This will allow you to see all the content.

```
ReportViewer1.SizeToReportContent = true;
ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.FullPage;
```

Comment: Are you sure about the first line? I am not finding SizeToReportContent property.

Comment: @bcsanches, that comes from one of my asp.net pages, sorry I thought winforms would have a similar function.

Comment: I am not seeing it, but the "FullPage" is giving a good result so far. Thanks